# server side code mixed with client side code - best practices

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Inside a given php script, I have the following:

```
<script>

    function showMember() {

           return $.ajax({ //Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

                type: 'get',

                //A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
                url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('member'); ?>',
    ...
```

This works, if I place this  inside the php file.

But this seems not to be a good way for organizing things, and I would wish to place all this code, on a separate .js file.

What is the proper way for dealing with those scenarios ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267894/what-the-best-way-to-handle-server-side-tags-inside-of-a-js-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use two approaches to make data created at server-side accessible to the client-side:

1) 'data transfer' object, filled by server-side scripts. For example:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
  $data = [
    'urls' => [
      'createSomething' => $this->createUrl($from, $something),
      // ...
    ],
    'labels' => [
      'createSomething' => $this->cms($labelName),
      // ..
    ],
  ]
?>
<script>
  var dto = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
$.ajax(dto.urls.createSomething, {}, function() { 
  alert(dto.labels.createSomethingSuccess);
}
```

2) dataset attributes, again, filled by the server. For example:

PHP:

```
<button data-target-url="<?= $this->createUrl($from, $something) ?>"
     >Something</button>
```

JS:

```
$('button[data-target-url]').click(function() {
  var targetUrl = $(this).data('targetUrl');
  $.post(targetUrl...);
}
```

The second approach, to me, appears to be most useful when there's some UI-related set of attributes still calculated at server-side - for example, plugin settings.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to split your php and javascript code. What you can generate is a base url so javascript can generate it's own urls. Generate those variables with php in your html.

Example in your html and php

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  var BASE_URL = <?=$baseUrl?>;
  </script>
  <script src="external.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can use the variable BASE_URL in your external.js

```
function showMember() {

       return $.ajax({ //Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

            type: 'get',

            //A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
            url: BASE_URL + "member",
```

This is a simple scenario that a lot of websites use. Generate global script variables in body before including external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a javascript function and send url as function parameter.

```
showMember(<?php echo $this->createUrl('member'); ?>);
```

In js catch and use it .

```
function showMember(posturl) {
return $.ajax({ //Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

                type: 'get',

                //A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
                url: posturl,
```

Comment: But in that case, there's not a total separation either, isn't it ? showMember javascript is still executed on the php code. Am i wrong?

Comment: If you want to use php values inside javascript then total seperation (which you mean by)is not possible. You have to pass the php values to js from your php file.