# How can i write php and javascript mix

Tags: javascript, php

This is a php page

```
echo '<script>
            function myFunction() {

                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Advertiser ID : '.$advr_id.', This advertiser has campaign also!") == true) 
                {'.
                    while ($row_camp = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $camp_id = $row_camp["camp_id"];
                    }

                .'}
                  else{};
            }
       </script>';
```

I am getting error before while and after while. How can i concatenate them?

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way, you can't mix server side script to your client side script functions. you can see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263087/server-side-code-mixed-with-client-side-code-best-practices)  for best practices (by storing it to some array in script then use it).

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)

Comment: Can not: Java Script to be run in a browser on your computer, while the php running on the Web server side.

Comment: What is he point in assigning a PHP variable to a value in side javascript..Where you are not even using the variable assigned in the while loop for your javascript.

Comment: You cant echo while loop.

Answer (score 0):

May be in this mode, may be I miss some variable but this is the idea
Try this, because I change it

**PHP**

```
 <?php
 ?>
   <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x;
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Advertiser ID : <?php echo $advr_id; ?>, This advertiser has campaign also!") == true)  

  {
             <?php echo 'x="ok"; alert(x);';
        /* while ($row_camp = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $camp_id = $row_camp["camp_id"]; //but may be echo something here is need?
                }*/ 
      ?>

            } else {
                x = "You pressed Cancel!"; alert(x);
            }
        }
    myFunction();
   </script>
```

Comment: I removed while loop and echo "Hello" at that php portion its not working.

Comment: i just edited, removed the while part with echo "Hello"; to check if its working or not.

Comment: @M Talha Afzal     Well, now when you set up your web page and database encoding to utf-8, what is here not work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the downvotes, it's a common mistake in learning PHP JS stack.

Anyway, I think you need to understand how PHP (Backend) and Javascript (Frontend) interacts.

[image: From W3School]

Long story short, your `if` javascript code, should send a whole new request to your backend server (using ajax or a simple http request using html, you know, a form and a submit button) and let your `while` PHP code do the database deletion.

**Update**

Here's a very basic example

*view.php*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var x;
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Advertiser ID : '<?php echo $advr_id; ?>.', This advertiser has campaign also!") == true) {
            window.location = '/delete.php?id=<?php echo $advr_id; ?>';
        } else {
            x = "You pressed Cancel!";
        }
    }
</script>
```

*delete.php*

```
<?php

$advr_id = $_GET['advr_id'];
// delete from database
```

Comment: May be he not this need but need `<script><?php echo 'some text'; ?></script>  to simply prind a javascript in html  witch will run on client side?

Comment: @Mitch well if he really needs to show $advr_id to the user as a confirmation, I don't see why not

Comment: What to do, is his code. May be hi want to show `x='some text'` but he don't know yet